# SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '05/20/2020'

Tags: sql, laravel

I'm making an app with laravel, this features a calendar. I'm using "fullcalendar" which is very restricting on date format and AFAIK only accepts 'yyyy/mm/dd'. I'm using the jQuery datepicker and have edited the formatting to make it work. That all works fine and on the insert for a long time I would never get this error, however suddenly it's started giving me this error after days of not having it. I really don't understand. Unless there's a way to change fullcalendar formatting to match the accepted formatting for SQL, which has not affected my app since now, then I'd love to hear it.

(error: `QLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect date value: '05/14/2020' for column`)

Thanks.

Comment: Show us how are you inserting that value on DB

Comment: `$event = Events::create($request->all());`

Comment: here's the model:
`protected $fillable = [
        'event_name',
        'event_date',
        'event_description'
    ];`

Comment: You should validate your date format first, then you can use mutator to change the format  to a datetime format (default in Laravel)

Comment: You would have to parse that date to a valid format before inserting into DB. Could you show us what's in the request? You can do a `dd($request->all());` and add the result in your question

Comment: `array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "(redacted)"
  "event_name" => "d"
  "event_description" => "d"
  "event_date" => "05/14/2020"
]`

Answer (score 0):

fixed it, my formatter was broken

Comment: Please write a complete answer on how you solve it so it can help other people with the same problem